# Why do the VM files on the host keep growing in size?

Tags: windows-10, vmware, vmware-workstation, disk-space

There is a VM with VMware Workstation. The files on the host keep growing and the physical disk runs out of space. I don't know why this is happening. The guest OS still has ~100GB free space. I noticed after each reboot of the guest it seems that the VMware files gradually increase in size. Is this supposed to happen or is there some way to stop this? I thought the size a VM takes only changes when you configure it to? Are there some junk files that I should be cleaning out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files keep growing because only used sectors are stored in the file.

And Windows happily keeps data in the "used" sectors even if they are freed in the guest OS. And because there is data in there, the VM cannot clean it up.

So if you set the maximum size if your guest physical storage larger than the available space on the host, it will eventually outgrow the available space on the host.

So set a reasonable maximum size, and the Windows will do a better job of re-using free but "dirty" sectors.

> I thought the size a VM takes only changes when you configure it to?

Yes. Which means to do the above, you need to create a new virtual disk, reinstall Windows, and copy your data.

Comment: How much less space should be allocated to the VM than is available on the physical disk? For example if the physical disk is 1TB shouldn't setting the capacity of the VM to 900GB be safe?

Comment: How many VMs are you running, you much of the disk do you expect the guest OS to use, do you want the guest OS to use network drives for data, do you want to use multiple virtutal disks? That's what you need to take into account when you size the disks.

Answer (score 0):

Machines keep growing because of updates, software additions and changes. This is an ongoing process.

You can regularly clean up and shrink virtual machines. I do this at least monthly and sometimes once in between if there has been a big update.

Windows Guests:  Use the VM "Manage Option"

Close down the Windows Guest so it is not running. Then use the Workstation menu "VM" .   Select "Manage" and then "Clean up disks" .  Let it run and the Windows machine will be smaller.

Linux Guests:.  Use the "shrink" command.

Keep the Linux Guest running.  Open a Terminal Window.

Run:    sudo vmware-toolbox-cmd disk shrink /  . Allow the command to run. Then a VMware GUI window opens that shrinks the machine. Allow that to finish. I always restart the guest after the shrink has completed.

My Kali guest runs around 20 GB long term (a year) and my Ubuntu guest runs around 20 GB long term (a year).

My Windows 7 guest (more software and some data) runs around 65 GB long term.

I make sure my Guest machine size (nominally 100 GB) is enough to hold the Guest machine long term.

Manage and Shrink will control disk space usage very well.